# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1225) to match target batch_size (25)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m getting the following error. I have tried every solution but nothing working.

I'm using VGG16 architecture, batch size 25, 3 channels images with shape 224x224 and I want to classify 9 classes.

Down bellow is attached my fc layer

```
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)
    )

    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, torch.nn.Conv2d):
            m.weight.detach().normal_(0, 0.05)
            if m.bias is not None:
                m.bias.detach().zero_()
        elif isinstance(m, torch.nn.Linear):
            m.weight.detach().normal_(0, 0.05)
            m.bias.detach().detach().zero_()

def forward(self, x):

    x = self.block_1(x)
    x = self.block_2(x)
    x = self.block_3(x)
    x = self.block_4(x)
    x = self.block_5(x)
    logits = self.classifier(x.view(-1, 512))
    probas = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)

    return logits, probas
```

Anyone with the solution? Kindly reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call the forward pass in your code? Where do you define batch size to be 25?

Comment: It seems like the data on which you're performing inference (either during or after training) has a different dimensionality (len = 1225) than the labels you're comparing the model output to (len = 25). Make sure the number of samples in X_train equals the number of labels in y_train, and the number of samples in x_val equals the number of samples in y_val.

Comment: @DWKOT thanks! I found a small issue in the code so the dimensionality of the samples did not match

Answer (score 0):

OP needed to match up the dimensionality of the samples they were calling their model on, and their labels (in other words, there should be 1 label per datapoint).